# ¿Cómo obtener los índices de un array?

Tags: javascript

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente

```
const array1 = [
  [ '01', 'FA' ],
  [ '01', 'CFDI40' ],
  [ '02', '01' ],
  [ '02', '04' ],
  [ '03', '1' ],
  [ '03-IMP', 'TRASLADO' ],
  [ '03-IMP', 'RETENCION' ],
  [ '03-ADU', '21  80  1871  0999999' ],
  [ '04', 'TRASLADO' ],
  [ '04', 'TRASLADO' ],
  [ '04', 'TRASLADO' ],
  [ '04', 'RETENCION' ],
  [ '05', '1.0' ],
  [ '05', 'R' ] 
    ];



const evaluar = (element) => element[0] === '04' && element[1] === 'TRASLADO';

console.log(array1.findIndex(evaluar)); //respuesta 8
```

Si consigue obtener el índice, obteniendo el 8, a lo cuál no se como realizar para que me devuelva todos los índices que cumplan con esa condición.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo te recomendaria que hagas uso de `forEach()`

```
    <script>
    const array1 = [
      [ '01', 'FA' ],
      [ '01', 'CFDI40' ],
      [ '02', '01' ],
      [ '02', '04' ],
      [ '03', '1' ],
      [ '03-IMP', 'TRASLADO' ],
      [ '03-IMP', 'RETENCION' ],
      [ '03-ADU', '21  80  1871  0999999' ],
      [ '04', 'TRASLADO' ],
      [ '04', 'TRASLADO' ],
      [ '04', 'TRASLADO' ],
      [ '04', 'RETENCION' ],
      [ '05', '1.0' ],
      [ '05', 'R' ] 
        ];
    
    
    
    
    array1.forEach(function(index) {//recorremos el array
      if(index[0]=== '04' && index[1] === 'TRASLADO'){ //hacemos la sentencia 
        console.log(array1.indexOf(index)) //si se cumple muestra sus posiciones
    
      }
      
      
    
      
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias! así es como pensaba obtener la respuesta!